# Routing Error undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to solve this error:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I am trying to set custom validations method in model but i am getting

> Routing Error undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass

This is article model code

```
# article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :category_id, :title, :body, :is_publish, :publish_date, :feature_image_url
    validates_numericality_of :category_id, greater_than: 0
    validates_length_of :title, minimum: 5
    validates_length_of :body, within: 5..200
    validates_uniqueness_of :title

    validate :publish_date_cannot_be_more_than_one_month_from_today
    def publish_date_cannot_be_more_than_one_month_from_today
        if publish_date > (Date.today + 1.month)
            errors.add(:publish_date, "Can't be more than 1 month from today")
        end
    end
end
```

> This is code for articles_controller.rb
>   articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @articles = Article.all
    end
    def new
        @article = Article.new
    end
    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)
        if @article.save
            redirect_to articles_path
        else
            render action: "new"
        end
    end
    def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        @category = Category.find(@article.category_id)
    end
    def edit
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end
    def update
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        if @article.update_attributes(article_params)
            redirect_to articles_path
        else
            render action: "new"
        end
    end
    def destroy
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        @article.destroy
        redirect_to articles_path       
    end
    a = Article.new

    a.publish_date_cannot_be_more_than_one_month_from_today 
    private

    def article_params
        params[:article].permit(:title, :body, :is_publish, :publish_date, :category_id, :feature_image_url)
    end
end
```

Comment: Add your article model to the question, and use code (text) instead images.

Comment: Could you add some code snippets? Specifically article model and article controller

Comment: how to solve this?can someone tell me

Comment: Seems like `publish_date` is nil so it's throwing an error when you try to compare a nil value to a date

Comment: Can you post the whole error message (with stacktrace)

Comment: if i enter the date thorough form then only it should compare in my program but i am not able to run it

Comment: undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass

Rails.root: /home/shivakumara/wd-aug/rails/Blog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/article.rb:10:in `publish_date_cannot_be_more_than_one_month_from_today'
app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:38:in `<class:ArticlesController>'
app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

Comment: check the instance see if there is a publish_date

Answer (score 1):

Remove these two lines from your article controller.Its outside your actions

```
a = Article.new

a.publish_date_cannot_be_more_than_one_month_from_today
```